# Getting unknown type : import in groovy in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: groovy, devops, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to create a Jenkins Pipeline Script using groovy. However, the `import` statement is giving me a compilation error - Unknown Type : Import. Not sure why.

[image: Screenshot attached here]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should define `import jxl.*` at the top of the pipeline script, e.g.

```
import jxl.*

node {
    stage('Execute Tests') {
        try {
           dir('.') {
               sh '......' // etc.
           }
        }
    }
}
```

When you added it inside `node {}` block Jenkins was looking for a method instead of import class statement. The good convention is to put all import statements at the top of the Groovy file.

Comment: If you are looking to do this for a pipeline library, where there are multiple .groovy files, you can do so just above the first function in the groovy file that needs the import.